# Oracle Adf navigation Pane

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am trying to create **ADF** menu model using navigation pane. So, I get `var` property of navigation pane `null`. I created task flow and I also created menu model of that **task-flow.xml** file then setting `value` property of navigation pane as `#{root_menu}`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the necessary code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: i create task_flow in adfc_config file then i create root_menu file of adfc_config

Comment: I reffers this doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_43/jdtut_11r2_43.html Plz help

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get your question. What is your question?